org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationException: oops while parsing JsonPath.parse
Stacktrace :
org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationException: oops
at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.parse(JsonPath.java:647)
I am writing a test case in which I am parsing json string using jsonPath. Its giving me an error. Its working in local machine but failing Github Action

Please share the workflow

Fixed ...It occurred because I haven't closed MockStatic in junit 5
